# Update primary value only if secondary value is not empty or nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have this piece of code and I want to make sure that the value of the first variable ( df['Given Name'] ) only gets updated if the second variable ( df['Maiden Name'] ) is not empty or nan .

```
df['Given Name'] = df['Given Name'] + ' ' + df['Maiden Name']
```

what is the shortest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is add values only if match conditions with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) chained with `&` for bitwise AND by compare not equal empty values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Given Name':['a','b','c'],
                   'Maiden Name':['d',np.nan,'']})

m = df['Maiden Name'].notna() & df['Maiden Name'].ne('')
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Maiden Name, dtype: bool

df.loc[m, 'Given Name'] += ' ' + df.loc[m, 'Maiden Name']
print (df)
  Given Name Maiden Name
0        a d           d
1          b         NaN
2          c
```

Comment: The original variable gets updated to an empty string if the secondary variable is empty as well... It loses its value... that's my problem from the start.

Comment: @a7madx7 - Answer was changed to `&` intead `|`

Comment: @a7madx7 - Is possible create some sample data, be free change `df = pd.DataFrame({'Given Name':['a','b','c'],
                   'Maiden Name':['d',np.nan,'']})` if not working like you need?

Comment: For the second time you don't fail to amaze me with ur readiness and quickness <3

Answer (score 0):

One option could be (assuming that there are no surrounding spaces in `Maiden Name` or they are not important):

```
df['Given Name'] = df['Given Name'] + (' ' + df['Maiden Name']).str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
m = df['Maiden Name'].notna() | df['Maiden Name'].str.len().gt(0)

df['Given Name'] = np.where(m, df['Given Name'] + ' ' + df['Maiden Name'], df['Given Name'])
```